# How to install Liquidsoap & Airtime on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, repository, installation, centos6, liquidsoap

That's the question, i already try some tutorials but i don't get any one to works

What repositorys are needed? Is there any repo than i can add than have it to install it directly? Is there any way to avoid using Debian Box?

I wanna keep the server without graphic interphase, although the webinterphase of Airtime is acceptable.

I'm trying to use it to Broadcast music from an external HDD, to transmit when the DJ's will not be on air, like an AutoDj function

I'm using icecast for the server, i do some test and it works, but i wanna automatize it and then i must add liquidsoap and/or airtime for this.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Any suggestion of another software to do this than will be actualy supported would be very welcome.

PS2: If you think i can receive a better answer in another StackExchange place, or think you know a forum, or a place/tutorial that can work, please let me know ;)

I already try IRC btw...

PS3: I mostly post it here because maybie some of you or know the answer or know a better/alternative answer that can post.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118352/how-to-install-liquidsoap-airtime-on-centos-6-5